# Function Definition: Returning a list of even numbers from list of integers

Tags: python, list, function, variable-assignment, definition

Use the function **print_even_values** with an input of an integer list and prints each even number on the list. Calling **print_even_values([2, 8, 1, 9, 0, 19, 24])** would produce this output in the shell window:

2
8
0
24

My approach is:

```
def print_even_numbers(n:list) -> list:

'''Return a list of even numbers given a list of integers'''
for x in list:
    if x % 2 == 0:
        return(x)
 assert print_even_numbers([2, 4, 2, 4, 5, 6]) == [2, 4, 2, 4, 6]

 assert print_even_numbers([4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 9]) == [4, 2]
```

, but there is an error. Also, how do I make my output similar to the question? (i.e.

```
 [2, 4, 2, 4, 6]
```

vs.(separate line)

```
2
4
2
4
6
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are returning a number when it is even, instead of returning the list of even numbers. You should store a number when it is even and then return the list:

```
def print_even_numbers(number_list):
    even_numbers = [] # define the empty list of even numbers
    for number in number_list:
        if number % 2 == 0: # check if number is even
            even_numbers.append(number) # if it is, store it
    return even_numbers # Last step returns the list of even numbers
```

Comment: Isn't your return statement indented too far? Shouldn't it be on the same level as the for statement? Otherwise, you'll always return on the first iteration of the loop, and always with a list of either zero or one numbers.

Comment: You're right, it was not indented correctly. I've accepted you're edit, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well also you can use longer version that looks like this:

```
def generate_evens():
    result = []
    for x in range(1, 50):
        if x % 2 == 0:
            result.append(x)
    return result


print(generate_evens())
```

And you have a short one using this:

```
def generate_evens1():
    return [x for x in range(1, 50) if x % 2 == 0]


print(generate_evens1())
```